# Hive jdbc resultset server side pagination

Tags: jdbc, hive

I am implementing a web app using hive jdbc to extract data. Considering that the size of result data could be million level, server side paging is a must. However, is there any direction or ideas on pagination on hive jdbc result set?

Currently I have two solutions:

1. Using RowNum(). The problem here is that I need to parse the query and modify it.
2. Runing the query every time and extract a pagesize of results. The problem is performance, the `rs.next()` takes tones of time.